# How to Create an array from the result of the API call in React Redux

Tags: api, redux

I get all the IMDB Movie IDs of the popular movies using an API. Then I call another API to fetch the movie details for each movie ID and push them into an array. However, when I'm checking the array content, it only contains the data that I pushed most recently. How I can store all the result values in the array so that I can display them on a page later.

**index.js ( Action )**

```js
import axios from "axios";
const url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=";
    
// The First API Call which gives me all the ids
export function getIMDBtitle() {
  const output = axios({
     method: "GET",
     url: "https://imdb8.p.rapidapi.com/title/get-most-popular-movies",
     headers: {
       "content-type": "application/octet-stream",
       "x-rapidapi-host": "imdb8.p.rapidapi.com",
       "x-rapidapi-key": "************************",
       useQueryString: true,
     },
     params: {
        purchaseCountry: "US",
        homeCountry: "US",
        currentCountry: "US",
     },
  })
    
  //The 2nd API call that gives me the details but takes one id at a time
  export function getMovies(id){
    const output = axios.get(`${url}${id}&&apikey=******`)
      return {
        type: "GET_MOVIES",
        payload: output,
      };
  }
```

**View File to call the 2nd API after getting a result from 1st API and Pass to it as a props**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { getMovies } from "../Actions";
    
class GetMovies extends Component {
  render() {
    const rederDetailes = ({ titles }) => {
      if (titles) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < titles.data.length; i++) {
          var id = titles.data[i].substring(7, titles.data[i].length - 1);
          this.props.dispatch(getMovies(id));
        }
      }
    };
    
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h1>Movies</h1>
          {rederDetailes(this.props)}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
    
GetMovies.protoType = {
   dispatch: PropTypes.func,
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
   var a = [];
   a.push(state);
   console.log(a);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GetMovies);
```

**The Reducer**

```js
export default function (state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_IMDB_TITLES":
      return { ...state, moviesTitle: action.payload };
    case "GET_MOVIES":
      return { ...state, moviesDetail: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
    }
}
```

**The Store**

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import promiseMiddleware from "redux-promise";
import logger from "redux-logger";
import Reducer from "../Reducers";
    
let Store = createStore(Reducer, applyMiddleware(promiseMiddleware, logger));
    
export default Store;
```

**The Result is on the console**

```
Array(1)
    0:
    GetMoviesTitle:
    moviesDetail:
    config: {url: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt6394270&&apikey=******", method: "get", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), …}
    data:
    Actors: "Charlize Theron, Nicole Kidman, Margot Robbie, John Lithgow"
    Awards: "Won 1 Oscar. Another 21 wins & 51 nominations."
    BoxOffice: "N/A"
    Country: "Canada, USA"
    DVD: "N/A"
    Director: "Jay Roach"
    Genre: "Biography, Drama"
    Language: "English"
    Metascore: "64"
    Plot: "A group of women take on Fox News head Roger Ailes and the toxic atmosphere he presided over at the network."
    Poster: "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZjlhOWE3YjktY2MzOC00ZmQ1LWIwNjgtZmVhZmFjZGExMzgyXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMDA4NzMyOA@@._V1_SX300.jpg"
    Production: "N/A"
    Rated: "R"
    Ratings: (2) [{…}, {…}]
    Released: "20 Dec 2019"
    Response: "True"
    Runtime: "109 min"
    Title: "Bombshell"
    Type: "movie"
    Website: "N/A"
    Writer: "Charles Randolph"
    Year: "2019"
    imdbID: "tt6394270"
    imdbRating: "6.8"
    imdbVotes: "71,438"
    __proto__: Object
    headers: {cache-control: "public, max-age=86400", content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8", expires: "Fri, 09 Oct 2020 17:43:06 GMT", last-modified: "Fri, 09 Oct 2020 16:43:06 GMT"}
    request: XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}
    status: 200
    statusText: "OK"
    __proto__: Object
    moviesTitle: {data: Array(100), status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
    __proto__: Object
    __proto__: Object
    length: 1
```

Comment: Not sure why are you using `Redux` for this? Also, the usage of Redux is wrong. Your actions should be a pure function, it should not have any side-effects ( no API calls )

Comment: It's my Project. I have to make it in `Redux`. can you please tell what's wrong in the **Action**? It's  a function already

Comment: Look into using “thunk”. It allows you to make async api calls in action creators and also allows you to dispatch multiple actions at a time.

Comment: Create a sandbox link. Your project is wrong on so many levels. Your API calls should be separate from redux, either use `redux-thunk` or call API on your React component.  I recommend spending some time looking at `redux` tutorials on Youtube and then rebuilding your project.

Comment: Hi Sandip, welcome to SO. I found this from the Facebook group. Please don't post API keys in the question. replace them with placeholder characters whenever you are posting.